# Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2

Getting the following exception while **log4j-api-2.18.0.jar** file. However, it was not observed in **log4j-api-2.16.0.jar**

> **Runtime Exception:**
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil

I am trying to load the PropertiesUtil file in one of my applications, but the latest jar file is throwing the following error:

**Full Stack Trace**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.status.StatusLogger.<clinit>(StatusLogger.java:78)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:61)
    at cybermation.commonservice.logging.CybLog4jLoggingConfigurer.initializeLogger(CybLog4jLoggingConfigurer.java:54)
    at cybermation.plugins.appservices.CybAppservicesPluginDriver.prepare(CybAppservicesPluginDriver.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at cybermation.agent.plugins.manager.CybPluginManager.a(CybPluginManager.java:343)
    at cybermation.agent.plugins.manager.CybPluginManager.loadPlugins(CybPluginManager.java:511)
    at cybermation.agent.CybAgentDriver.runApplication(CybAgentDriver.java:340)
    at cybermation.agent.CybAgentDriver.main(CybAgentDriver.java:510)
```

PropertiesUtil.class file is there in the **log4j-api-2.18.0.jar** under **util** directory.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Upgrading the log4j-api and log4j-core version to 2.20.0 resolves the problem

Comment: Nice to know: one of [LOG4J-3579](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3579), [LOG4J-3624](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3624) and  [LOG4J-3642](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3642) must have been at the root of the problem. Can you write an answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment upgrading `log4j-api` and `log4j-core` version to `2.20.0` resolves the problem.